# Why Qt formatTime in ShortFormat is different for similar locales?

Tags: qt, datetime, format, locale, kde-plasma

How C locale differs from other locales so that QT treats it a little bit differently?

|  | LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 | LC_TIME=C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Qt.formatTime(Source) | 00:00 | 00:00:00 Why seconds shown? |
| Qt.formatTime(Source, "hh:mm:ss") | 00:00:00 | 00:00:00 |

I use KDE Plasma with default Breeze theme. I was trying to make my lockscreen to show time with seconds.
Normally I use LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8" and the lockscreen shows time without seconds (like 12:34). If I switch LANG="C" locale, then the time is shown with seconds (like 12:34:56).
I can set LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8" and add a LC_TIME="C" (so it differs from lang). But setting LC_TIME to C has side effect that the day names in lockscreen are shown in English. I wanted to keep the day names in Russian, while still show seconds.

The file used to describe text for time in lockscreen is '/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/components/Clock.qml'. And it has such line:
`text: Qt.formatTime(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"]")`
If I change it to
`text: Qt.formatTime(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"], "hh:mm:ss")`
then my problem is solved. (Taken from [here](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=130484) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783184/how-to-display-kde-lock-screen-time-in-24-hour-format)).

**But I am interested why when the second parameter is omitted, QT adds seconds for C locale and does not add seconds for other locales?**

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#formatTime-method) says: If format is not specified, time is formatted using Locale.ShortFormat using the default locale. And [timeFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#timeFormat) in ShortFormat is: For example, LongFormat for the en_US locale is h:mm:ss AP t, ShortFormat is h:mm AP.

I have compared the definition of C locale and en_US locale files (in /usr/share/i18n/locales/) and did not notice difference in time specification:
For C:`t_fmt   "%H:%M:%S"` and for en_US: `t_fmt   "%r"`. But %r and %H:%M:%S is the same thing.

So why in C locale QT adds seconds?

Comment: I mean, if I for example want to change en_US locale to show seconds, then what place do I edit? Let's say I create a custom locale en_US_seconds.UTF-8, based on original, but t_fmt edited from %r to C's %H:%M:%S. This will not make it, right?

Answer (score 1):

It shows the seconds because that's simply how the short time format for the C locale is defined.

The time display depends both on the locale (first argument) and on the time format (second argument) specified, defaulting to the given locale's short format when not specified, and the default short and long time formats themselves depends on the locale. C's short format has the seconds, en_US's doesn't:

```
> QLocale::c().timeFormat(QLocale::ShortFormat)
"HH:mm:ss"
> QLocale(QLocale::English, QLocale::UnitedStates).timeFormat(QLocale::ShortFormat)
"h:mm AP"
```

That's why the seconds are shown when defaulting to the locale's short format with the C locale (which is `HH:mm:ss`), or when explicitly specifying the format as `hh:mm:ss`, but not when defaulting to the locale's short format with the en_US locale (which is `h:mm AP`). See [QLocale::TimeFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#timeFormat).

If you're using Plasma, you can also see what the times in short and long format look like for all available locales by opening Region & Language system settings and clicking the button for modifying the time locale.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Oh, I see now it in plasma settings. I looked there, but was confused, as it had long standard format line for all entries, but I needed to look the secondary line of entries.
Regarding question, what are exact lines for short time format and for long time format  in the locale definitions? The man is here: https://man.archlinux.org/man/locale.5 I Only see t_fmt, without said if it is for long or short time format.

Comment: Hm, I don't actually know. I'm not even sure (and couldn't find out with some googling) if the short and long format is a GNU standard and if so where it's defined, or whether that's something Qt stipulated. In this case it would indeed be interesting to know why they decided to go with that definition, and if this was the question then my answer is kind of a non-answer. Sorry I can't be more helpful here; keep me posted if you find an answer.

Comment: Yeah, wanted to know it, to see the difference in definitions. Yeah, possibly it's qt's own thing. Thanks anyway.